# Unable to retrieve the value of the argument passed through the URL

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to learn Django by working on a small project.
The website has 3 buttons on the home page (Home.html). Each button represents a type of user.
Upon clicking a button, the user is taken to the signup page. In the GET request to the Signup page, a variable named user_type is set based on the value of the button that was clicked on the home page.

The variable is passed on to the Signup.html template and is used as a parameter for the POST request. My intention is to use this parameter from the URL in my signup view and set the database field named user_type.
But I am unable to retrieve the value of the parameter in the view. I get an empty string when I print u_type. Even though the URL in the browser shows the value of user_type. Kindly help me with this issue. I am also open to trying alternate ways to achieve the same results.

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import SpaceUserForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Users/Home.html')

def signup(request, u_type=''):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SpaceUserForm(request.POST)
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        print(u_type)
        if form.is_valid():
            user.user_type = str(u_type)
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse("User was created successfully.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("There was an error.")
    else:
        form = SpaceUserForm()
        context ={}
        print(list(request.GET.items()))
        if request.GET.get('addAgent'):
            user_type = 'AG'
        elif request.GET.get('addCustomer'):
            user_type = 'CU'
        elif request.GET.get('addWarehouseOwner'):
            user_type = 'WO'
        context['form'] =SpaceUserForm()
        context['user_type'] = user_type
    return render(request, 'Users/SignUp.html', context)
```

Home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please choose an option</p>

<form action="/signUp">
    <span>
    <input type="submit" name="addAgent" value="Agent" />
    <input type="submit" name="addCustomer" value="Customer"/>
    <input type="submit" name="addWarehouseOwner" value="Warehouse Owner" />
    </span>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

SignUp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>AbstractBaseUser Form Example</title>
</head>

<p>This is an example of a signup form with custom fields based on a model that
subclasses the AbstractBaseUser model in Django.</p>

<p>Aside from a couple of fields Django always retains for any user (is_active,
last_login and password), this option enables you to restrict the fields to whatever
you want.</p>

<form action="{% url 'Users:signup' u_type=user_type %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {{ form.as_table }}
      </tbody>
    </table>
      <p>&nbsp</p>
      <p><button type="submit">signup</button></p>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

app_name = 'Users'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^signUp', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^signUp/(?P<u_type>)', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'login', views.logedin, name='login')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things a little bit here. It probably would be easier if you used links with a query string instead.

```
<a href="signup?user_type=Agent"></a>
<a href="signup?user_type=User"></a>
<a href="signup?user_type=WarehouseOwner"></a>
```

Then in your django view you can use:

```
type = request.GET.get('user_type')
```

and it will have the value of your user type.